# ¿Por qué recibo el error Allowed memory size of 2097152 bytes exhausted cuando instalo WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Estoy tratando de hacer una instalación limpia de la versión `Wordpress 5.3.2` en español ocupando `php 7.2` y recibo este error extraño:

> Allowed memory size of 2097152 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 65536 bytes) in /home/public_html/wp-load.php on line 54

Estuve investigando y todos dicen que lo modifique en el php.ini el parámetro `memory_limit`. En mi caso lo tengo a 512MB y también mencionan que lo modifique en mi `wp-config.php`. El detalle que tengo es que si se supone la instalación es limpia el archivo de wp-config.php aún no existe, entonces no tiene caso modificarlo ni se debería hacer (hasta donde tengo entendido).

Espero pudieran aconsejarme a saber qué es lo que está pasando.

Comment: Hola Fernando, recuerdo que cuando empecé en Wordpress tenía mucho ese problema. Revisa la pregunta enlazada y la respuesta. El error ocurre cuando algún proceso de WP solicita demasiada memoria. Eso puede deberse a plugins malos que tengas instalados, o a limitaciones de tu hosting. Desde hace unos años estoy en hosting compartido de Bluehost y jamás ha ocurrido este error. Pero aprendiendo PHP reduje mi cantidad de plugin, de unos 10 o 12 que usaba antes, hoy día sólo uso dos plugin y todo lo demás lo he programado yo mismo. Los plugin recargan nuestro WP.

Comment: Muchas gracias, @A.Cedano Aprecio mucho tu orientación y la respuesta que me acabas de hacer, me ha sido de mucha ayuda.